# How to get height of topLayoutGuide?

Tags: ios, swift

```
 moviePlayer = MPMoviePlayerController(contentURL: url)
 moviePlayer.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y:{layoutguide.height}, width:
 self.view.frame.width, height: 300)
 self.view.addSubview(moviePlayer.view)
```

viewcontroller have an attribute named "topLayoutGuide", but it seems not I wanted.

I know how to implement in storyboard, ***in code***, I can't get the height of Top Layout Guide. I searched for hours getting nothing.

[image]

[image]

Below is wanted.

[image]

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You can get the topLayoutGuide value as its `length` property:

```
// Inside your viewController
self.topLayoutGuide.length
```

Since it is a single value (i.e.: it does not have a height and width) they just called it `length`. Same holds for bottomLayoutGuide.

Hope this helps

One more thing to mention, in the apple doc for this property:

> // As a courtesy when not using auto layout, this value is safe to refer to in -viewDidLayoutSubviews, or in -layoutSubviews after calling super

Use this property in these two functions will get you the accurate value, since the layout has been initialized. If you use it in the `viewDidLoad` function, this property will be 0.

Comment: Pay attention at when you ask for this value. Of course it might change when layout changes.

Comment: self.topLayoutGuide.length is always 0.0

Comment: When do you ask for it? Probably in `viewDidLoad` you'll get 0.0 since no layout has been done. On 'viewDidAppear` you might get a different value.

Comment: Also, `viewDidLayoutSubviews` is the moment when auto layout has finished it's job for the current view controller.

Comment: @Morgan Wilde you are right. Just Albert might pay attention if he _re-layout_ views after didLayout ... just in order to not looping ;-)

Comment: viewDidLayoutSubviews is key point, I'm newer for ios thanks a lot! I got it just at viewDidLoad.could you edit your answer for someone else?

Comment: You saved my time

Comment: `topLayoutGuide ` is deprecated now for iOS 11

Answer (score 40):

If someone is looking for how to calculate the height of insets of SafeLayoutGuide available for iOS 11 because Top and Bottom Layout Guide are deprecated now, you can find it in:

```
view.safeAreaInsets
```

Notice that Top and Bottom Layout Guide were a part of ViewController, and now SafeLayoutGuide is a part of the main view of the ViewController.

Comment: Top and Bottom Layout Guides are still part of ViewControllers.

Comment: @CoderNinja yes, I didn't say they were not, I said they are deprecated in iOS 11. Maybe my last sentence was confusing so I edited it.

Answer (score 23):

This gets the length (in points) of the portion of a view controller's `view` that is overlaid by translucent or transparent `UIKit` bars.

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    let topSpace:CGFloat
    let bottomSpace:CGFloat
    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        topSpace = self.view.safeAreaInsets.top
        bottomSpace = self.view.safeAreaInsets.bottom
    } else {
        topSpace = self.topLayoutGuide.length
        bottomSpace = self.bottomLayoutGuide.length
    }
}
```