# How to get safe area top,bottom,right,left value in iOS?

Tags: ios, ios11

Xcode iOS how to get safe area top ,bottom ,right ,left value
like this -> [How to get height of topLayoutGuide?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30284036/how-to-get-height-of-toplayoutguide)

```
// Inside your viewController
self.topLayoutGuide.length
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The safe area insets is a `UIEdgeInsets` struct. You can access the components like this:

```
 view.safeAreaInsets.left
 view.safeAreaInsets.right
 view.safeAreaInsets.top
 view.safeAreaInsets.bottom
```

etc

Comment: Also note that similar to `topLayoutGuide`, these insets are only filled after viewDidLayoutSubviews.

Comment: I tried this with iPhone X simulator and got bottom inset zero. Is that normal? Shouldn't it take into consideration the position of the home indicator?

Comment: @enigma safeAreaInsets are available on the call to view.layoutSubviews and subsequently viewController.viewDidLayoutSubviews

Comment: Using self.view.safeAreaInsets.top in viewdidlayout crashes the app.

Comment: @enigma Try accessing `safeAreaInsets` from the view controller's `view` property. `safeAreaInsets` appears to be all zero on subviews.